# Django Rest Framework--deny access to list but not to retrieve

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I'm having some trouble with permissions.  I know how to use `has_permission` and `has_object_permission`, but I have a number of cases where someone needs to be able to access `retrieve` but not `list`--e.g., a user has access to their own profile, but not to the full list of them.  The problem is, `has_permission` is always called before `has_object_permission`, so `has_object_permission` can only be **more** restrictive, not less.

So far, the only way I've been able to do this is to have more permissive permissions and then overwrite `list()` directly in the `ViewSet` and include the permission check in the logic, but I'd be able to actually store all of this logic in a Permissions class rather than in each individual viewset.

Is there any way to do this?  Right now I feel like I'm goign to have to write a ViewSet metaclass to automatically apply permissions as I want to each viewset method, which isn't really something I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments to `has_permission` is `view`, which has an attribute `.action`, which is one of the five "LCRUD" actions ("list"/"create"/"retrieve"/"update"/"destroy").  So I think you could use that to check, in `has_permission`, whether the action being performed is a list or a retrieve, and deny or allow it accordingly.